# How are lists written in Korean?

Tags: grammar

In English, we create lists like what I've written below.

Things to do:

- Buy a broom
- Eat a sandwich
- Call my brother

Is the same kind of list done in Korean? If so, how?

Edit: I'm also looking for formatting and punctuation. Is the same list formatting and punctuation used for listing things?

Comment: Possibly using the 으(ㅁ) style final verb ending?

Comment: @B.Alvn (으)ㅁ final verb ending is never put in a to-do list, as using (으)ㅁ would imply the stuff has been done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, but I believe these would be done with the -기 nominalization form:

- 빗자루 사기
- 샌드위치 먹기
- 형에게 전화하기

Comment: 형에게 전화하기 would be more natural

Comment: @nglee thanks, I just updated it. Not sure why I left off the -에게. I think I was just trying to be brief in a list.

Comment: Do Koreans use different list formats or punctuation?

Comment: @LanceClark They use numbered or bulleted lists similar to English.

Comment: This is very natural and almost right. But native Koreans don't use a word '비' as the meaning of broom. It can be confused with another homonym 비(rain). So, it would be better to translate broom into '빗자루'.

Comment: @jungyh0218 thanks, I updated it. Always appreciate native speaker input.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ryanbrainard's answer, sometimes "-할 것" is also used.  It has a stronger feeling: "should do X!"

In this style, the list would be:

- 비 살 것
- 샌드위치 먹을 것
- 형에게 전화할 것

Comment: Do Koreans use different list formats or punctuation?