# How to write 'Study a little Korean every day' in Hangul?

Tags: translation, hangul

I'm making a to-do list and want to add 'Study a little Korean every day' on it, but I want to write it in Hangul. Would it be like this: 조금 한극어 하루하루 공부하다? (I'm a beginner, sorry if this is wildly wrong)

Comment: If you're making a to-do list, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/how-are-lists-written-in-korean/2912 also contains some information that might interest you.

Answer (score 4):

My (native Korean) wife suggests: `한국말을 매일 조금씩 공부한다`

Here are a couple of things that a Korean-as-second-language learner might share, even if they require tweaking from another native speaker:

1. `하루하루` is "everyday" or perhaps more like "day in/day out", yes, but it's more difficult to put into play than the more common `매일`. "Study every day!" should be `매일 공부해`...you might use `하루하루` like this: `하루하루가 즐겁다`..."day in and day out things are enjoyable".
2. The *conjugated infinitive form* of an *action verb* (like "study") must end in `한다` not `하다`.  `공부하다` is the "dictionary form" but cannot be used outside of...the dictionary.  In the case of the *descriptive verb* `즐겁다`, there is no ㄴ/는 added during conjugation.
3. `씩` is like methodology...so when you say "give me a little" you might say `조금 주세요` but in specifying your methodology about how you will study you need to `조금씩` to be specific and clear about that.

Comment: If I am not wrong, it should be spelled 조금씩.

Comment: @Taladris thanks, I updated it. I always appreciate input.

Comment: "한국어를"  seems to be more natural than "한국말을". 
if you want to use "한국말을" , then "한국 말을" is correct. (spacing)